# Latest version of mongorestore very slow when restoring backup made with old version of mongodump

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore, backups

I am using mongorestore 4.2 
`mongorestore --gzip --archive=my-archive.gz` to restore a backup made with mongodump 3.2(ish?) and the process is very, very slow.  Like I haven't even seen one completed because it's been running for 3 days slow.  Is this a reported issue with version mismatch between mongorestore and older mongodump backups?

Comment: MongoDB doesn't support restore backups from other version. Starting in version 4.2, mongodump uses Extended JSON v2.0 (Canonical) format for the metadata files, so it's impossible to restore 3.2, 3.6, 4.0 mongodump files for 4.2

Comment: @Valijon So if I go back to my original snapshot, update the database from 3.2 to 4.2 and then run mongodump, I should be able to mongorestore with 4.2?

Comment: The problem is not easy to update from 3.2 to 4.2, you need to migrate from-to: 3.2 - 3.4, 3.4 - 3.6, ... 4.0 - 4.2. keep backup for 3.2 and start migration in order

Comment: @Valijon although it's generally not recommended to mix versions, it is possible to restore to 4.2 a dump made with 3.2 (I just tried it to be sure). It's not supported going in the other direction though. The actual backup data files are in BSON so it wouldn't have this issue. Only the metadata that contains information about indexes etc. are in extended JSON 2.0. I believe mongodump/mongorestore don't break compatibility and ensure that both extended JSON versions are supported.

Comment: @wsc how big is my-archive.gz. Are you seeing a progress bar? If possible, could you run `mongorestore -vvvvv ...` and post what it's doing?